# Displaying CIImage after using CIFilter in GLKView

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-image

I always get an error message when trying to present an CIImage filtered by CIFilter inside of an GLKView. The Error is "CoreImage: EAGLContext framebuffer or renderbuffer incorrectly configured!
Invalid shader program, probably due to exceeding hardware resourcesCould not load the kernel!"

The following code I use to display the Image :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    EAcontext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!EAcontext) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }
    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.EAcontext;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_renderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderBuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBuffer);

    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB8_OES, 768, 1024);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBuffer);

    coreImageContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:self.EAcontext];

    [self updateView];
}

- (void)updateView
{
    UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Moskau1.jpg"];
    CIImage *outputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:myimage];

    [coreImageContext drawImage:outputImage inRect:self.view.bounds fromRect:[outputImage extent]];    

    [EAcontext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}
```

The Viewcontroller is a `GLKViewcontroller`. EAContext is of type CIContext.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The "Invalid shader program, probably due to exceeding hardware resources" and "Could not load the kernel!" are actually distinct error, but the former seems to lack a linebreak. I got this problem yesterday, and it seems there are a few sources of this problem:

- Check the frame buffer status to ensure it is complete - `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` should return `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` - see the [OpenGL ES programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) for an example.
- In my case, I had added a depth buffer to the framebuffer used by Core Image. Core image evidently didn't like this - once I removed the depth buffer renderbuffer, the both error messages went away, and Core Image did its thing.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and deleting of the depth buffer removed the error.